# After I added Sentry to react-native project, apps deployed to itunes store crash (on Android or ios simulator it works fine)

Tags: xcode, react-native, sentry

I added react-native-sentry to a react-native project. I followed this manual: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/

Everything worked fine on Android and ios emulator. But when I tried to archive an app in xcode I got this error.

**React native symbol handling failed**

The Sentry build step failed while running in the background. You can ignore this error or view details to attempt to resolve it. Ignoring it might cause your crashes not to be handled properly.

If I click 'Show Details; I get this

`error: EOF while parsing a value at line 1 column 0`

I followed the advice from here https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry/issues/135 and edited Build Phases > Upload Debug Symbols so now there is only this line there

`export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties`

The error still persisted. So I decided to ignore it. In this case after I upload the version to Itunesconnect and install it with a TestFlight it crashes immediately on start.

If I run it on a simulator or install it directly an iphone it works fine.

It also works fine on Android.

Could you give me any advice what can be done to make it work on Apple Store too?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. And I changed my job.

Answer (score 1):

For me this error was signaled by Xcode because of some problems when running the build scrips.

Using:
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native
`@sentry/react-native": "^1.0.9`

I fixed it keeping the `index.ios.js` always in the root folder (before that I had it in a `src` folder and trying to use a custom build script to take it from `src`)

I set the build scripts in Xcode to be similar to the ones from sentry docs:

**Build RN code and images script:**

```
// sentry properties file located in `ios` folder
export NODE_BINARY=node
export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties

../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli react-native xcode \
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

**Upload debug symbols script:**

I have this script as the last one in Build Phases

```
 export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties

 ../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli upload-dif 
 "$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH"
```

**Note:**

**1)** I haven't tried yet to move sentry.properties file as common for both android and iOS, placed in root folder (with import ../sentry.properties in scripts) but I think that should work too.

**2)** I used the terminal to test directly the release build:

`react-native run-ios --configuration Release --simulator "iPhone 8"`
or

`react-native run-ios --configuration Release --device "Your Device Name"`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was a space included in the name of the hard disk I use to keep the Project, Derived Data and Archives. Looks like the Sentry CLI script doesn't like spaces in the path to the project and it crashes there.
It was enough to rename the disk and update paths to Derived Data and Archives and all is well now.